# TabsAdapter Android Fragments

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have three Fragments, TabsAdapter is holding all of them , My question is how can I set the default one , one which will be on screen when you start the app, My default one is first but i need to my default fragment in tabsAdapter to be in the middle.
When I open app my First.class is on screen and I must to navigate to Home.class,
Can I putt my Home.class to be default and to stay in the middle ?

My code :

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.first),First.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.home),Home.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.third),Third.class, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [setCurrentTab(int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) or `setCurrentTabByTag(String tag)` on your `tabHost` while creating it.